# Is it possible to update Visual Studio's CSS validation?

Tags: css, visual-studio

I'm using VS2013 and am getting a lot of incorrect feedback on CSS3 syntax (particularly flex elements). Is the validation schema baked into a VS release or can it be updated somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem in the past with Visual Studio 2010 (only CSS 2.1).

The short answer is yes, it is possible to add new schemas and use them instead of the default ones.

You can take a look at the visual studio gallery, but I cannot confirm if this will work on later versions of Visual Studio.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I can't find anything for 2013 at all. It seems incredible to me that they don't consider HTML5 and CSS3 support important. Maybe they're still hoping the whole CSS thing is just a fad, and that we'll come to our senses and return to styling with the Properties tab. Anyway, I'll keep an eye out for VS vNext stuff.